# Retain German umlauts in Visualforce

Tags: jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I am trying to retain the German umlauts in the radio button check selected text in Visualforce. The SOQL returns the value as is, but jquery replacing them by 'uml;'. The code below where i am trying to capture the value selected and where its getting converted. attr('id') contains a concatenation of ID and text ( having umlauts )[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKobc.png)

```js
function GetSelectedParentIds(){
            var selectedIds = '';
            
            $j('.chkRadioParent:radio:checked').each(function(){
                selectedIds = selectedIds + $j(this).attr('id') + ',';                
            });
                        
            return selectedIds;
        };
```

Kindly assist anyone.

Thanks in advance.